# How to truncate a string after a word in scala

Tags: regex, scala

Given the following string...

```
"localhost:9000/one/two/three"
```

I want to truncate it **after** the word `two` and get

```
"localhost:9000/one/two"
```

I've implemented the methods `truncateBefore` and `truncateAfter` like this:

```
def truncateBefore(s: String, p: String) = {
  s.substring(s.indexOf(p) + p.length, s.length)
}

def truncateAfter(s: String, p: String) = {
  s.substring(0, s.indexOf(p) + p.length)
}
```

These methods work and return the expected results:

```
scala> truncateAfter("localhost:9000/one/two/three", "two")
res1: String = "localhost:9000/one/two"

scala> truncateBefore("localhost:9000/one/two/three", "two")
res2: String = "/three"
```

Is there a better way to do this in scala? Preferably with a regex?

Comment: Scala adds some nice stuff to Java's regex which you could certainly use to solve this problem.

Comment: Do you want to return both with one call for example? I think for String manipulation this solution is good enough.

Comment: @barnesjd, this solution do not use regular expresssions.

Comment: @GáborBakos yeah I know... I'm suggesting it as an alternative, which he is asking for.

Comment: This isn't something you could use with String's `takeWhile` is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splitting after the first literal, without much regex-fu (pun intended).

```
scala> implicit class `split after`(val s: String) {
     | def splitAfter(p: String): (String, String) = {
     |   val r = (Regex quote p).r
     |   r findFirstMatchIn s map (m => (s.substring(0, m.end), m.after.toString)) getOrElse (s, "")
     | }}
defined class split$u0020after

scala> "abcfoodeffooghi" splitAfter "foo"
res2: (String, String) = (abcfoo,deffooghi)

scala> "abc*def" splitAfter "*"
res3: (String, String) = (abc*,def)
```

Answer (score 7):

One option using **regex**:

```
val beforeAfter = "(^.*two)(.*)$".r

scala> val beforeAfter(after, before) = "localhost:9000/one/two/three"
after: String = localhost:9000/one/two
before: String = /three
```

Another option using **split**:

```
scala> "localhost:9000/one/two/three" split ("two")
res0: Array[java.lang.String] = Array(localhost:9000/one/, /three)
```

These are not super robust solutions in case you don't have a word `two` in the input, but you can handle it accordingly...

One more using **regex** in **for** comprehension:

```
scala> val beforeAfter = "(^.*two)(.*)$".r
beforeAfter: scala.util.matching.Regex = (^.*two)(.*)$

scala> (for {
     |   matches <- beforeAfter.findAllIn("localhost:9000/one/two/three").matchData
     |   tokens <- matches.subgroups
     |  } yield tokens).toList
res0: List[String] = List(localhost:9000/one/two, /three)
```

which is safe if no matches found:

```
scala> (for {
     |   match <- beforeAfter.findAllIn("localhost").matchData
     |   token <- match.subgroups
     |  } yield token).toList
res1: List[String] = List()
```

Comment: @j3d if you go this regex route, you'll certainly want to make the `two` an argument.  Be sure to use regex quotes around it: `\\Qtwo\\E`

Comment: @barnesjd Probably Pattern#quote http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String) would be more easy to understand later.

Comment: Where should I put these quotes? This works also without quotes: val beforeAfter = ("(^.*" + pattern + ")(.*)$").r

Comment: @j3d `val beforeAfter = ("(^.*\\Q" + pattern + "\\Q)(.*)$").r` or as was also suggested: `val beforeAfter = ("(^.*" + Pattern.quote(pattern) + ")(.*)$").r`.  This is important to prevent weird issues if the string in `pattern` ever happens to contain special regex characters.

Comment: Ah OK, thanks. I've implemented it as a String extension - see here below my answer. Thank you very much for your great support!

Comment: This result might be unexpected: `val beforeAfter(after, before) = "localhost:9000/one/two/three/two/four"` (takes the longest pattern, the second "two")

Answer (score 1):

Obviously not efficient, but it works.

```
scala> val url = "localhost:9000/one/two/three"
url: String = localhost:9000/one/two/three

scala> url.reverse.dropWhile(_ != '/').reverse
res0: String = localhost:9000/one/two/
```

With an index:

```
scala> url.drop(url.reverse.indexOf('/'))
res1: String = host:9000/one/two/three
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, thanks to everybody... and here is my solution:

```
package object typeExtensions {

  implicit class StringExtensions(val string: String) extends AnyVal {

    def truncateAfter(pattern: String) = beforeAfter(pattern).map(_._1).getOrElse(string)
    def truncateBefore(pattern: String) = beforeAfter(pattern).map(_._2).getOrElse(string)

    private def beforeAfter(pattern: String) = {
      if (string.contains(pattern)) {
        val beforeAfter = ("(^.*" + Pattern.quote(pattern) + ")(.*)$").r
        val beforeAfter(before, after) = string
        Some(before, after)
      } else None
    }
  }
}
```

Any suggestion to improve the code above is more than welcome ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, as an alternative to regex solutions, it's also possible to pattern match a `String` by [unapplying a string interpolator](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/StringContext$s$.html#unapplySeq(s:String):Option[Seq[String]]):

```
"localhost:9000/one/two/three" match {
  case s"${prefix}two${suffix}" => s"${prefix}two"
  case _                        => "no match"
}
// String = "localhost:9000/one/two"
```